# PyGTK: Controlling interface from within joined thread

Tags: python, multithreading, join, gtk

I have a thread in PyGTK, inside my mainloop. It's a Timer, so it needed to be joined with .join(). The problem is, I now cannot edit my UI from in that thread - change text and so on - because of the .join(). Is there a way I can change things from outside (well, you know what I mean) the mainloop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using a Timer thread, use [`glib.timeout_add`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--timeout-add) to do your thing.
It works together with gtk's mainloop and runs in the same thread, so you don't have to do anything special.